# Can I use LFS Test Server from Github?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

So I need a LFS server that I'm going to run locally, without any extra features. I tried it out before using this https://github.com/git-lfs/lfs-test-server and it works fine, but I'm not sure why its named as a test server. Can I just use it as the proper one? Has anyone used it like this? Are there any options I should change? I wolud also like to change the title so it doesn't say LFS Test Server at the top so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is marked as a test-server because they do not deem it 'production stable'.

Quote from [README.md](https://github.com/git-lfs/lfs-test-server/blob/master/README.md) :  "[...] and is not in a production ready state"

This means it should not run directly on the internet. It might compromise the safety of your server and/or data.

Also, it might corrupt your data. But I do beleive it will not. ;-)  Backups are your friend.

I am running git-lfs tucked behind an apache2 running [https](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html), [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) and user-authentication. So it will only be touched by my valid users. (Make sure to firewall the port, default 8080, to be only available from localhost)

Also, using https is strongly recommended as the lfs-test-server can only do basic authentication.